# Spring Webflux: efficiently using Flux and/or Mono stream multiple times (possible?)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have the method below, where I am calling several ReactiveMongoRepositories in order to receive and process certain documents. Since I am kind of new to Webflux, I am learning as I go.

To my feeling the code below doesn't feel very efficient, as I am opening multiple streams at the same time. This non-blocking way of writing code makes it complicated somehow to get a value from a stream and re-use that value in the cascaded flatmaps down the line.

In the example below I have to call the userRepository twice, since I want the user at the beginning and than later as well. Is there a possibility to do this more efficiently with Webflux?

```
    public Mono<Guideline> addGuideline(Guideline guideline, String keycloakUserId) {
        Mono<Guideline> guidelineMono = userRepository.findByKeycloakUserId(keycloakUserId)
                .flatMap(user -> {
                    return teamRepository.findUserInTeams(user.get_id());
                }).zipWith(instructionRepository.findById(guideline.getInstructionId()))
                .zipWith(userRepository.findByKeycloakUserId(keycloakUserId))
                .flatMap(objects -> {
                    User user = objects.getT2();
                    Instruction instruction = objects.getT1().getT2();
                    Team team = objects.getT1().getT1();
                    if (instruction.getTeamId().equals(team.get_id())) {
                        guideline.setAddedByUser(user.get_id());
                        guideline.setTeamId(team.get_id());
                        guideline.setDateAdded(new Date());
                        guideline.setGuidelineStatus(GuidelineStatus.ACTIVE);
                        guideline.setGuidelineSteps(Arrays.asList());
                        return guidelineRepository.save(guideline);
                    } else {
                        return Mono.error(new InstructionDoesntBelongOrExistException("Unable to add, since this Instruction does not belong to you or doesn't exist anymore!"));
                    }
                });
        return guidelineMono;
    }
```

Comment: i dont have an IDE so cant write an example but you could start by fetching the instruction. keep that `Mono<Instruction>` then you fetch the `User` and `flatMap` the user and fetch the team then you `flatMap` the team and build a `Mono<tuple>` consisting of `Mono<Tuple<User, Team>>`. Then you take your 2 `Monos` and use `zipWith` with a `combinator` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWith-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction- and build a `Mono<Tuple<User, Team, Instruction>>` that you can flatMap over.

Comment: So basically fetch 2, then fetch 1, then combinate into 3. You can create Tuples using the `Tuples.of(...)` function

Comment: was about to write you basically what @Toerktumlare is suggesting. Guess you should be able to do it from his description.

Comment: @p.streef go ahead and write an answer if you feel like it. I don't have an IDE currently to write something. But if you feel like you want then no problem.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you so much. That seems to have done the trick in making it more efficient and also readable. The approach that I am taking was in the right direction, so this is also a confirmation for that. Thanks a lot. What I do notice is that all these streams are being openend with MongoDB, which takes a lot of connections towards the DB, compared to blocking programming.  Still need to investigate this, because the connections seem to be stacking up and not closing quickly.

Comment: @vv01 investigate, and if you can't figure something out then you'll have to write a new question. Im no mongo pro, but there are a lot others on this forum that are. good luck!

Comment: If a Mono represents the result of an expensive function then you can use the cache operator to ensure it´s only invoked one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll post my earlier comment as an answer. If anyone feels like writing the correct code for it then go ahead.

i don't have access to an IDE current so cant write an example but you could start by fetching the instruction from the database.

Keep that `Mono<Instruction>` then you fetch your `User` and `flatMap` the `User` and fetch the `Team` from the database. Then you `flatMap` the team and build a `Mono<Tuple>` consisting of `Mono<Tuple<User, Team>>`.

After that you take your 2 `Mono`s and [use `zipWith` with a `Combinator` function](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWith-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction-) and build a `Mono<Tuple<User, Team, Instruction>>` that you can flatMap over.

So basically fetch 1 item, then fetch 2 items, then `Combinate` into 3 items. You can create Tuples using the `Tuples.of(...)` function.